# Difference between ansible's wait_for and wait_for_connection

Tags: ansible

I've read the docs but these modules seem to do very similar things:

- [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html)
- [`wait_for_connection`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_connection_module.html)

How do they differ? When should I use one or the other?

(There is also the `ping` module, which can be used in a similar way, but it doesn't wait unlike the modules above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- *wait_for_connection* waits **only** for the answer of the target host to ping executed from ansible control node.
  It's the same of using "*ping some_hostname*" on command line and wait for packets.
- *wait_for* can be configured to wait on a chosen port, for a chosen state (started, stopped, and so on), for matching a chosen regex in response...
  All accepted parameters are explained in the module documentation.